# ParseKit Grammars don't support "allowsGroupingSeparator". Why?

Tags: objective-c, parsekit

A ParseKit grammar containing the number state "allowsGroupingSeparator" does not appear to be working.

```
@allowsGroupingSeparator = YES;
@start = number;
number = Number;
```

Parsing a number containing a grouping separator will only match digits up to the separator. This grammar use case does not appear to be covered by any of the tests in the GitHub ParseKit framework. (Also none of the other number states appear to work with grammars.)

Answer (score 0):

Developer of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here.

This was an oversight. I have added support for `allowsGroupingSeparator` in [head of trunk on google code](https://code.google.com/p/parsekit/).

Your usage above is correct and should now work.

Comment: No big deal but the change was made to branches/branch-dev-new-factory rather than head of trunk (r273).